# Refresh the browser client side without hitting the server

Tags: javascript

I would like to be to refresh the browser window without hitting the server, I’m guessing javascript is a good way to go? I have the following code but I’m unsure what it’s doing exactly!

```
<body onload="JavaScript:AutoRefresh(5000);">

<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
        function AutoRefresh(t) {
            setTimeout("location.reload(true);", t);
        }
//   -->
</script>
```

If that’s just refreshing the browser client side then great but if not how should I go about it?

Comment: Doesn't refreshing the browser hit the server, by definition?

Answer (score 2):

Both `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />` (refreshes every 5 seconds) and `window.location.reload` refresh the browser client side but fetch data from the server.

Its not possible to refresh or reload a page within getting data from server. If you want to do client side refresh like clearing a HTML5 canvas, you have to adopt specific means like setting width works for clearing a canvas, & other methods for other objects as per your needs.

Comment: **Both** those techniques cause the browser to rerequest the page from the server. A simple test shows that the access log gets an another entry each time either of them triggers. So they *do* affect the server.

Comment: The point of both those techniques is to get fresh data from the server for a frequently updating page.

Comment: Gopi1410, **clearing a HTML5 canvas** may be along the lines of what I need to do and Quentin, I get the XY problem now. I have posted a link to my real problem below in Quentin’s answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to be to refresh the browser window without hitting the server

You can't, by definition. Refreshing the page means making a request for a fresh version from the server.

Comment: Correct, it can't be done. You might try asking a question about [the problem you think 'refreshing the browser client side' will solve](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Just have, but I've been trying to get to the bottom of this for a while now and wanted to make sure I’d exhausted all I have first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266968/refresh-the-browser-once-on-load