# Refresh the browser once on load or clear DOM

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a dynamic MVC4, jQuery Mobile application that works for the most part quite well. I have an auto posting dropdown list that selects a list from the database via the following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#TownID").live('change', function () {
        //$("#TownID").change(function () {
            var actionUrl = $('#TheForm1').attr('action') + '/' + $('#TownID').val();
            $('#TheForm1').attr('action', actionUrl);
            $('#TheForm1').submit();
        });
    });
</script>

<p>
     @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchTown", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TheForm1" }))
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("TownID", (SelectList)ViewBag.TownId, "Select a Town")
    }
</p>
```

The problem is it only works properly the first time a search is performed unless I click refresh. I don’t think this has anything to do with MVC, I think the problem is with AJAX and jQuery Mobile.

**Edit:**

The first time I search **www.mysite.com/Home/Search/2** yields a result and woks fine, but the second time something seems to be left behind in the DOM??? and it looks for:

```
www.mysite.com/Home/Search/2/2 also
```

I get 404 errors in my log and **“Error Loading Page”** but it still finds the results and displays the page correctly!

Then with a third search I get the error 404’s in my log and “Error Loading Page” but it has grown and now looks for:

```
www.mysite.com/Home/Search/2/2
www.mysite.com/Home/Search/2/2/2 also
```

This then continues to grow after every search until at some seemingly random point on each test, it seems to give up and I get error 505

**Additional Edit:**

**The code works perfectly if I take jQuery Mobile out of the question**

Can anyone tell me what might be going on here?

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you told it to. On each change of the dropdown list, it is appending another id to your actionurl. I'm not sure why you are trying to do a form submission this way.

Comment: Also you should use 'bind' instead of 'live' - otherwise thanks to jQuery mobile you may get multiple submissions if you leave the page and then come back to it.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, it’s the only way I know how too. I've been working on this for about 6 months on and off and have exhausted the net trying to find a better way. If you know a better way to auto submit the form, please share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is one for the future, MVC and jQuery Mobile don't seem to blend completely right now. Maybe MS's response to the issue is Single Page Applications!

SPA may satisfy Danial also?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of: <s>`$(function () {`</s>

And replace it with: `$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pageinit', function () {`

Please read the big yellow sections at the top of this page: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html

You can't rely on `document.ready` or any other event that only fires once per page. Instead you have to get used to using jQuery Mobile's custom page events like `pageinit` so your code will work no-matter when the page is added to the DOM (which you don't know when this will happen in a jQuery Mobile website). There are a ton of events, so again, please read the documentation I linked-to above.

Comment: Hi Jasper, that has made matters worse, I have an edit above!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, dynamically generated html using a server side templating engine blows. I really don't understand what value people see in it.

My guess is that it used to make sense 10 years ago before AJAX became popular, and has just hung in there ever since because people have this feeling that it is "the right way to do it". It isn't. ESPECIALLY for mobile web apps.

Secondly, it looks like you are trying to do pretty simple search. All this MVC4 garbage makes it difficult for you to see what is really happening though. You don't need to append parameters to your URL for a simple form submission like this. In fact your TownId should already be part of the POST data when you submit, so you can just remove the URL modification bit.

Alternatively, don't use a form submission, but just a GET and AJAX. I don't know what your app is doing here, but I imagine you want to display the results on the page dynamically somehow, so a GET is more than enough.

Use your developer browser tools (F12) to see what exactly is getting submitted when you do the submit - it really helps. And for your next project, abandon MVC4! "[Well established design patterns](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4)" my foot.

Comment: I doubt I will be abanding MVC4 anytime soon, it allows me to build a dynamic mobile website in about five minutes! But I know what you mean about appending the parameters, that’s where my problem lies. I just don’t know anything about javascript so I’m stumbling around here. If someone would re write the code for me and show me exactly what I am doing wrong we can put this one to bed.

Comment: Sorry, that was the problem from the beginning, if I don't send the parameters through I get a "null entry for parameter" error!

Comment: My point exactly. 5 minutes to get something working - then 6 months on and off to get it working right :) I don't know what the MVC4 framework is expecting, but to do the form submit, all you need is something like this: $('#myPage').bind('pageinit', function () {
            $("#TownID").bind('change', function () {
                $('#TheForm1').submit();
            }
        }

Comment: This is the only thing that I cant get to work in MVC on a mobile. I can only guess you don't know the answer, you are an open source person and MVC scares you!

Answer (score 0):

I have been bothered by this problem for a long time
There are same select element in the DOM I think so...
and I used $('.SelectCSS:last').val()
It seen work well.

I come from China , English is poor...

Comment: Thanks Yesterday, it's nice to know someone else is having the same problem. I've tried everything but nothing works. Do you mean in my example, should I try $('#TownID:last').val(). I tried that but no change.